# Arbitrary mocking of object properties

Tags: javascript, ruby, mocking

I come from a Ruby background, and am trying to test a Javascript library which interacts with an object retrieved a JSON api end-point.

How would I recreate the following Ruby in Javascript?

```
class ArbitraryMock
  def initialize(property_hash)
    @property_hash = property_hash
  end

  def method_missing(*args)
    @property_hash[args.first] || ''
  end
end
```

EDIT: method_missing is a dynamic method that is invoked whenever a method does not exist. The default version of this method raises a NoMethodError (Javascript would return undefined I believe). By overriding the method in a way such as above, it allows you to do things like the following:

```
some_object = ArbitraryMock.new(foo: 'bar')

some_object.foo
=> 'bar'
some_object.bang
=> ''
```

Comment: What does method_missing do? In this context is it used to return either the value of the property, or an empty string? You might be able to do something with getters/setters if that's correct.

Comment: Please see the edited version of my question.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope it's of some use.

Answer (score 0):

Since [Javascript doesn't have an equivalent to *method missing*](http://yehudakatz.com/2008/08/18/method_missing-in-javascript/), the only way I could think of doing this was with getters and setters.

Initialise the params. Each property has a getter and setter. The getter returns the value of a private variable or an empty string; the setter sets the private variable with the value to which it's assigned.

```
var params = {
    get name() { return this._name ? this._name : ''; },
    set name(name) { this._name = name; },
    get dog() { return this._dog ? this._dog : ''; },
    set dog(dog) { this._dog = dog; }
};
```

Set up the arbitraryMock object and initialise. The initialise method pins the getters and setters to the object.

```
var arbitraryMock = {
    initialise: function (params) {
        for (var k in params) {
            this[k] = params[k];
        }
    }
};

arbitraryMock.initialise(params);
```

Testing for the value of name, initially, returns an empty string.

```
console.log(arbitraryMock.name); //  empty string
```

But if you assign a value to `name`

```
arbitraryMock.name = 'Basil Fawlty';
console.log(arbitraryMock.name); // 'Basil Fawlty'
```

This works for other properties you've added to the object.

```
console.log(arbitraryMock.dog); //  empty string
arbitraryMock.dog = 'Terrier';
console.log(arbitraryMock.dog); // 'Terrier'
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJWnJ/).

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained the ruby code - method_missing is a dynamic method that is called when you try calling a method on an object that isn't defined.